# Ошибка при подключении css

Tags: html, css, django

Столкнулся с проблемой подключения css к одному элементу, дело в том, что у меня есть две  ссылки, все в одном html файле и подключены к одному css файлу.Первый работает как надо, второй почему-то css вовсе не видит.

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="register_page"><input type="button" value="register" class="buttom_register"></a>

<a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="singup_page"><input type="button" value="singup" class="buttom_singup"></a>
```

строка с классом register работает нормально => c singup нет. Я полностью скопировал первую строку, но заменил value и class, но даже так не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А стили вы писали дополнительно для ссылки c классом `.singup_page` ?

```css
.buttom_register {
  color: red;
}

.buttom_singup {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="register_page"><input type="button" value="register" class="buttom_register"></a>

<a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="singup_page"><input type="button" value="singup" class="buttom_singup"></a>
```

Вообще - не правильно делать `<a href="">` вокруг `<input>`.

Сделайте либо:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="register_page">register</a>
<a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="singup_page">singup</a>
```

и опишите стили для ссылки, либо:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'account_login' %}'">register</button>
<button onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'account_signup' %}'">singup</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет про input. Разумеется для singup и register я отдельно прописывал стили

Comment: Я рекомендую переделать правильно на обычные ссылки, думаю, тогда все сразу станет нормально :)